# Spring JPA/Hibernate problem with updating entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Method in service is responsible for saving A Entity. A entity has @ManyToOne relation with B Entity. 
A Entity

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private B b;
```

B Entity

```
@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "A", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<A> A;
```

A Service method

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public ADTO createA (String username) {
        B b = findEntityByUsername(username);
        log.info("ACTUAL NUMBER OF A = {}", b.getA().size());
        A a = AMapper.buildA(b);
        ARepository.save(a);
        log.info("ACTUAL NUMBER OF A = {}", b.getA().size());
        return AMapper.buildADTO(a);
    }
```

While executing createA method, I'm calling ARepository.save to save entity, then im checking it in log if size of list changed, but it didn't. When I call createA method once again then it shows that the size of list changed and entity was saved. I want to have it in real time not after method was executed.

EDIT

Entity manager refresh method `entityManager.refresh(b);` helped me to refresh A entity to get updated size List of A entity. But to make it work I need `@Transaction` annotation on `createA()` method. 
Wrapping repo save() method in separate class to support transactional proxy didnt work.

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ASaveService {

    private final ARepository aRepository;

    public void saveA(A a) {
        aRepository.save(a);
    }
}
```

This is what works now

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public ADTO createA (String username) {
        B b = findEntityByUsername(username);
        log.info("ACTUAL NUMBER OF A = {}", b.getA().size());
        A a = AMapper.buildA(b);
        ARepository.save(a);
        entityManager.refresh(a);
        log.info("ACTUAL NUMBER OF A = {}", b.getA().size());
        return AMapper.buildADTO(a);
    }
```

Is there any other way to make it work? For example calling second `findEntityByUsername(username)` without entity manager?

Comment: The problem is probably because you have it in a `@Transactional` method. It will not update from DB as long as your are in the same transaction. You would need to fetch this after transaction is completed.

Comment: @grekier Even though I delete `@Transactional` it still doesn't update while method is executing but it's updated after

Comment: WHy should it? You aren't reloading `B` so why should it magically have `A` added to that representation?

Comment: @M.Deinum Reloading `B` with flush() method doesnt work

Comment: `flush` isn't a reload. You need to either call `refresh` with the entity or `flush` and `clear` the entitymanager and then reload `B`. Your edit isn't reloading either as it will take it from the first level cache. Part of your problem is that you aren't really managing the bi-directional relation ship, you are setting only 1 half and not the other.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum `entityManager.refresh(a)` works fine. Is there any other way to make it work? For example calling second findEntityByUsername(username) without entity manager and without `@Transaction`? Since it's not annotated with `@Transaction` then Hibernate is not commiting the SQL statement under one commit, am I right?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `@Transactional` but your lack of understanding how hibernate works. Either manage both sides of the relation (when adding it to the colleciton, set the reference on the other side as well and/or vice-versa) or refresh the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the repo save() calls in @Transactional methods in a new service class. They need to be a a separate service to support transactional proxy.

Comment: I updated my question. Now I'm reloading both tables but it doesn't. Also another call to method doesn't work

Comment: Very mysterious.. I have updated my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: Somehow it still didn't work, I edited question and updated the code and new service class like you suggested me too.